# best media sharing cms like youtube

Tags: video, content-management-system, media

We are trying to build a media sharing site. I want to use existing commercial or open source frameworks if they are available.

With these facilities :

1. support video advertise befor play video
2. convert video quality 
   change video quality when run vide like youtube (youtube player setting button) :
   for example : 
      3GP « - 144p 
      3GP « - 240p 
      FLV « - 240p 
      MP4 « - (Max 480p) 
      MP4 « - 720p

   change quality with setting button on player (like youtube setting button)
3. support utf-8 languages
4. allow the user to create channels
5. add embed link and download link
6. add comment
7. view media after the manager confirmed

And other facilities

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for something else but as i got your point, it seems to me that [mediadrop](http://mediadrop.net/) is that for which you are looking for. its open source too.